# Pythong - Telegram : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, connection, telegram

I have written python to broadcast message to ma telegram channel. but now i am getting

```
error 1
  443 too many connections, ssl problem, i 

error 2
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))
```

Source code:

```
token = 'ccccccc';
channelName = '@ccccc';
message = "test";

url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + channelName + '&text=' + message;
result = requests.get ( url, verify=False );
print ( result.content );
```

Comment: please follow question guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
fix typos, formatting, clear question, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the POST method instead of GET.

Try this;

```
from requests import post
from urllib.parse import quote as qt


token = 'your-token-here'
channelName = '@channel_id'
message = "test message"

post('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + channelName + '&text=' + qt(message) + '&parse_mode=markdown')
```

Comment: Thanks bro, but i am getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 341, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 761, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 238, in connect
    ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 279, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "D:\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 850, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "D:\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1108, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 597, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 245, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 309, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 341, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 761, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 238, in connect
    ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 279, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "D:\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 850, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "D:\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1108, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\works\Python\Sample\dummy.py", line 8, in <module>
    post('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + channelName + '&text=' + qt(message) + '&parse_mode=markdown')
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 109, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 415, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be in two cases:

1. The telegram was blocked in your country. *Use a VPN to prevent these errors.*
2. This bot was run as pulling, so you can try to connect as the second bot by same token - Telegram aborts this connection. Try to use greater delay time in the first instance of a bot or use webhooks.

Comment: It's not about code, need to understand full situation. Your code works for me.

Comment: Then i think, may be other plugin causing this issues, doubut on pandas and other recent plugin which i added, any idea ? . yes bro, this code works before .